# Functional equivalent of a For loop referring to consecutive elements in a list

Tags: list-manipulation, functional-style, map, pure-function, procedural-programming

I have implemented this function which smooths the values in a list by, if it encounters a zero, replacing this entry by the average of its two neighbours (apart from the first and last values of the list, which are left alone). The following works:

```
smoother[vTemp__] := 
  Module[{vTempSmoothed = ConstantArray[-1, Length[vTemp]], i}, 
    For[i = 1, i <= Length[vTemp], i++, 
      If[And[i > 1, i < Length[vTemp]], 
        If[vTemp[[i]] == 0, 
          vTempSmoothed[[i]] = Mean[{vTempSmoothed[[i - 1]], vTemp[[i + 1]]}], 
          vTempSmoothed[[i]] = vTemp[[i]]], 
        vTempSmoothed[[i]] = vTemp[[i]]]]; vTempSmoothed]
```

Testing the following on the list below returns the required result:

```
vTempTest = {1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 0, 11, 12, 0, 13};
smoother[vTempTest]
```

However, wanting to improve my knowledge of functional programming, I would like to know how to replace the above For loop with a more functionally-desirable alternative (for example `Map`, or `Apply`).

Does any one have an idea how I could do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are two possibilities. First, use `MovingMap`:

```
ClearAll[av];
av[{l_, 0, r_}] := (l + r)/2;
av[{_, m_, _}] := m;
```

and then

```
smoothMM[list_] := Join[{First@list}, MovingMap[av, list, 3], {Last@list}]
```

or, you can use in-place assignments:

```
smooth2[list_] :=
  Module[{copy = list, pos = Flatten[Position[list[[2 ;; -2]], 0]] + 1 },
    copy[[pos]] = (copy[[pos - 1]] + copy[[pos + 1]])/2;
    copy
  ]
```

The second one will be more efficient.

There are obviously infinitely many other ways to solve this.

Answer (score 7):

This duplicates the behavior of yours (no effect on zeroes at ends):

```
smoothee=ReplacePart[#, i_ /; i > 1 && i < Length@# && #[[i]] == 0 :> 
                                   Mean[{#[[i - 1]], #[[i + 1]]}]] &;

smoothee[{0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 0, 11, 12, 0, 13, 0}]

(* {0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 19/2, 11, 12, 25/2, 13, 0} *)
```

Here's a goofy (but quite fast) method:

```
goofy = (# + Join[{0}, BitXor[1, Unitize@#[[2 ;; -2]]], {0}] MeanFilter[#, 1]*3/2) &;
```

And a seriously fast way - note I've broken out the pieces, so you can see what's happening. You'd combine this into one function for real use. I compared to one of the faster answers:

```
vTempTest = RandomInteger[{0, 1000}, 500000];


Timing[

 x = vTempTest;
 zers = DeleteCases[Pick[Range@Length@x, x, 0], 1 | Length@x];
 means = Mean[x[[{# - 1, # + 1}]]] & /@ zers
 x[[zers]] = means;

 ]

f = fiter[vTempTest]; // Timing

x == f

(*

{0.015600, Null}

{6.380441, Null}

True

*)
```

Squeezing the last together into a function, and taking advantage of listability of functions like mean nets an extra speed bump:

```
fast1 = Module[{z = DeleteCases[Pick[Range@Length@#, #, 0], 1 | Length@#], c = #},
                c[[z]] = Mean[{c[[Subtract[z, 1]]], c[[z + 1]]}];c] &;

vTempTest = RandomInteger[{0, 500}, 1000000];

Timing[
 x = vTempTest;
 zers = DeleteCases[Pick[Range@Length@x, x, 0], 1 | Length@x];
 means = Mean[x[[{# - 1, # + 1}]]] & /@ zers;
 x[[zers]] = means;
 ]

f = fiter[vTempTest]; // Timing

ls = smooth2[vTempTest]; // Timing

f1 = fast1[vTempTest]; // Timing

x == f == ls == f1

(*

{0.093601,Null}

{11.356873,Null}

{0.327602,Null}

{0.078001, Null}

True

*)
```

NB - Timings on an old netbook...

Comment: That's great. Thanks for that. Does anyone know of any others that could also do the same job? I am interested to see a variety of functional alternatives! Cheers, Ben

Comment: @ben18785: I'll cook up some more if time permits, I'm sure others will have interesting solutions. NB: There is a bug in yours (unless it's intended) - if two zeroes are in sequence, you average using the already calculated average for the first zero...

Answer (score 3):

Yet another approach.

```
data = {1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 0, 11, 12, 0, 13};
filterF[{a_, b_, c_} /; b == 0] := (a + c)/2
filterF[{a_, b_, c_}] := b
fiter[data_] := Join[{data[[1]]}, filterF /@ Partition[data, 3, 1], {data[[-1]]}]

fiter @ data
```

> ```
> {1, 3, 4, 6, 8, 19/2, 11, 12, 25/2, 13}
> ```